# Facebook API - cannot fetch page profile image

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a page I cannot fetch the public profile image from. Why is that, and why does it happen?

The page in question is: (WARNING: NSFW-ish images of strippers, real sorry, only example I could find - no need to view the page anyway)
https://www.facebook.com/pages/Texas-Poolhouse/98758030102

I can access the page through the graph API. Notice that the results tell me the ID is 98758030102, as expected:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=98758030102

And even get the image URL this way too:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?method=GET&path=98758030102%2Fpicture

However, using the ID, I cannot fetch the image the way I normally do. I just get a blue question mark:
http://graph.facebook.com/98758030102/picture

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding the `access_token` GET parameter to the url makes sure users who are allowed to view the page image will see it (18yo++ in this case). I have, however, not found a way to, through the API, determine when or why pages are not accessible by certain users.

Comment: All tough there appears to be no way to confirm this, this seems like the most reasonable answer

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you're using an access token from a user who can see the page? I can see the correct image when using my own access token - if you're not using an access token you're limited to the information which is publicly available and given the nature of the page it's probably limited to adults only because of its alcohol and/or stripper content.

Comment: Good point - although I thought profile pictures were always public? Also, where do I get an overview over what information is available? I can't seem to find a way to ask the API whether or not the image will be publicly available.

Comment: They're always visible if you can see the page, but if you can't see the page you can't see the profile pic. If you can access a page with a user's access token, that user can see the page. if you can't, that user can't, so it doesn't matter what restrictions are in place because they can't / won't be able to see it regardless of what your app does

Comment: Sounds crazy - but I guess that means I'll have to set up fake profiles (under 18 etc) to test each and every page if they're available to my targeted group :S

Answer (score 2):

I realize that this is an old question but I will add my answer for future searchers since this worked for me.

You say that using this as the image URL does not work. http://graph.facebook.com/98758030102/picture

Well I got curious and changed the http:// to https:// and entered my page ID in place of yours and it worked.

I am assuming by turning the connection secure it allows the graphi api to fetch the image.

This URL should work.
https://graph.facebook.com/YOUR_PAGE_ID_NUMBER/picture

Comment: I see no difference between http://graph.facebook.com/98758030102/picture (http) and https://graph.facebook.com/98758030102/picture (https). This still seems to be an age/content restriction thing... the major problem is that it's very hard to check if a picture is visible to all users or not.

Comment: Hmm it worked for me when I changed it to https.
Is it being used inside an img tag as the source?

Comment: It's been a long time since I've used the facebook api, but I reckon it might have something to do with users only being logged on over https, hence https requests for images are served "for your user" (able to do age-restriction checks), while http requests are served publicly (showing the safe-by-default age restricted questionmark). Does the https request work if you're not logged in with facebook connect / if you're logged in with a <18 yo profile?