# Facebook page picture publishing working or not?

Tags: javascript, facebook, api

Reading the documentation of how to publish the page picture of a facebook page here:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/picture/

Is this POST endpoint working?

I am able to get the picture from the

```
GET /{page_id}/picture?redirect=0&height=200&type=normal&width=200
```

instead of

```
GET /platform/picture?redirect=0&height=200&type=normal&width=200
```

as it says in the docs (It consistently says /platform/ in all examples and ref.).

But whatever I have been trying when POST / Publishing to the endpoint:

POST /{page_id}/picture
with url as a field

I get:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#1) Could not fetch picture", 
    "type": "OAuthException", 
    "code": 1
  }
}
```

I tried both through the JS api and through the Graph API Explorer, using the page access token, posting with the url field.

Is this broken in the facebook graph api or am I doing something wrong here?

Step by step:

1. on the developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer -> Get Access token, and added manage_pages as extended permission
2. then GET me/accounts to get the page access token for my page (503383593111939): all 6 permissions is there.
3. copied access_token from me/accounts for page 503383593111939 into the access token input field in the same graph explorer and changed to POST /503383593111939/picture?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wcdouglas.com%2Fimg%2Flogo.png, tried to add the url as a field without urlencode aswell but with the same result

Answer (score 0):

The same happened with me. The only thing was that there was a `space` character after the query. Removing it would give you the desired result.

Try this query:

```
GET /{page_id}/picture?redirect=0&height=200&type=normal&width=200
```

I've just removed the `space` character in the end.

For post to work, you will have to do something like this:

```
POST /{page_id}/picture?url=http://images.com/img.jpg
```

For this, you'll be needing access tokens. You'll get those from [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#pagetokens).

Comment: Yes, it worked for me as well, the space was something that came up when I copied it in. But the POST / Publish command wont work in anyway I try.

Comment: @AndreasJ so is your issue fixed now?

Comment: No I cant get the publish to work. Are you able to update the page picture on that facebook page? making a POST to /{page_id}/picture with the field url as in the docs?

Comment: Oh wait! I'm getting a new error! Aargh! Something to do with authentication(#10). I'm on it. I'll tell you if I get something. Anyways, about the (#1) error you were getting, try the above query. Does that work?

Comment: Got it! Get the missing access tokens from the edited answer!

Comment: I still dont manage to update the picture, still the same error "message": "(#1) Could not fetch picture". Ok I go it through exactly what I am doing (created new page),

1. on the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/ -> Get Access token, and added manage_pages

2. then GET me/accounts to get the page access token for my page (503383593111939): all 6 permissions. 

3. copied access_token from me/accounts for 503383593111939 into the access token input in the same graph explorer and changed to POST /503383593111939/picture?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.wcdouglas.com%2Fimg%2Flogo.png

Comment: Sorry for thee formating in the above comment. even tried to add it as a field in the Graph Explorer without url encode it, but with the same result. (btw, the swedish flag I updated through facebook)

Comment: For some reason, I too am unable to get the page permissions. But, on the other hand, I didn't get a (#1)

Comment: Yeah, "(#10) Application does not have permission for this action" is what I get when using the wrong access token

Comment: I am able to get passed (#10) Application does not have permission for this action" by following the steps in the first post. But I am stuck at (#1) Could not fetch picture. I cant find anywhere someone using this function to publish a new profile picture, I have been looking into some java libs as well. They just have getters for it.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538078/facebook-api-cannot-fetch-page-profile-image